# How to display review in shopify product listing page

Tags: node.js, shopify, shopify-app

I am developing shopify app for write and display review. There are too many apps in shopify app store for reviews.

For product detail page, i set write and display review section with dynamic product_id.

But i am struggling with product list page.

Can anyone help me?

I will give you reward for help.

Answer (score -1):

Product Reviews allows you to show or hide the review listing by default.

To show or hide the reviews:

From your Shopify admin, go to Apps > Product Reviews.

Click Settings.

In the Review listing layout section, check or uncheck the box next to Show reviews on load.

Click Save.